# Voice activated offline voice recorder

Tags: recording, voice-dictation, voice-memo

Sometimes while driving or washing the dishes some idea pops up in my head while I am listening to music.

How may I record voice without touching the phone?

(Sometimes while driving in remote places I do not have Internet connection so using Siri will not work)

Comment: and what phone do we have? and what research have we done so far?

Answer (score 1):

## Audio Memos

This paid app lets you add a paid extension that allows you to have voice activated recording:

> - Voice activated rec. - stop recording silence.

If you don't like IAPs, then you can download [Audio Memos Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audio-memos-pro/id290160980?mt=8) from the same author (but it's more expensive than Audio Memos + IAP price.

## Smart Recorder

This paid app also lets you have voice activated recording:

> - Auto pause/voice activated recording